# Possible to specify 2 columns in one MySQL WHERE statement

Tags: mysql

My database table has (amongst other fields) the fields, 'firstname' & 'lastname' - however when i collect data from my user form i allow them to just specify 'name', for ease of data-entry. So, when i do the query i will look in both, 'firstname' & 'lastname' columns for the users 'name' search-term.

Im wondering is there a possible mySQL syntax to do this without resorting to this kind of thing:

```
... WHERE (firstname = 'barrios' OR lastname = 'barrios') AND ...
```

Something maybe like this:

```
... WHERE (firstname OR lastname = 'barrios') AND ...
```

I haven't actually tried this yet but syntactically it looks right - before i put it to the test does anyone know if its
possible

thanks all ...

Comment: As a rule of thumb, StackOverflow users will have expected you to have tried something before you come posting a question. Give your query a try (you don't need the parentheses) and if you have trouble, I'm sure someone would be glad to help

Comment: "Syntactically it looks right". Not exactly. It 'feels' right, but it is syntactically wrong, for it does not respect SQL syntax. The first query is very correct, and you will get used to it.

Comment: To follow-up on spryno's comment, if you don't have access to a console don't worry--there's [sqlfiddle](http://swlfiddle.com).

Comment: spryno724, @Gregorz- No problem i've never had a need to do this kind of query acrobatics but it got me thinking - had to do it on a live system so didnt want to chance it.@Brad Christie  - thanks ill try sqlfiddle

Comment: @Grzegorz actually, the expression is syntactically correct :) You won't get a syntax error if you try it. It's just that it doesn't do what the OP expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to, you can do it this way:

```
WHERE 'barrios' IN (firstname, lastname)
```

(But that’ll of course only work for an “equal” comparison, if you want to bring in LIKE or something later on, then you will have to resort to the “longer” syntax.)

Comment: but `'barrios' IN (firstname, lastname)` is essentially translated into `'barrios' = firstname OR 'barrios' = lastname` so it's still two comparisons..

Comment: Of course, I didn’t say it was otherwise. The question was about syntax, not about possible performance gains or something.

Comment: Hmm.. I re-read the question and yeah, you're right. I just assumed he was after efficiency, not syntax; otherwise it's a pretty silly question (+1)

Comment: @MikyDinescu / CBroe - Not a silly question at all and the 'IN' syntax is exactly what i was looking for, i wasn't looking for performance gains just a shorter less cumbersome syntax since there may well be many more clauses chained together a shorter syntax for the two name columns will make life a lot easier - id vote up if i had enough rep points

Comment: @FlimFlam, even if you can't vote up you can always accept the answer if it answered your question! That way you show you appreciation and even get a bit of rep in the process ;)

Comment: @MikyDinescu - accepted - forgot to do that (not intentional) just noobie nerves  -many thanks

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible to do that. You have do use the first syntax.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible to do that,will prompt syntax error. You have do use the first syntax.